# Lodash - Move object to first place in array than sort by another property

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have an array of object employees

[image]

```
    {
  "emp1": {
    "BusinessPartnerFormattedName": "Aleksandra Lewandowski",
    "EmpRoleCode": "BUP003",
    "EmpRoleType": "Employee",
    "EmployeeID": "E8000",
    "isAssigned" : true,
    "ObjectID": "00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"
  },
  "emp2": {
    "BusinessPartnerFormattedName": "Aleksandra Lewandowski",
    "EmpRoleCode": "BUP003",
    "EmpRoleType": "Employee",
    "EmployeeID": "E8000",
    "isAssigned" : true,
    "ObjectID": "00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"
  },
  "emp3": {
    "BusinessPartnerFormattedName": "Aleksandra Lewandowski",
    "EmpRoleCode": "BUP003",
    "EmpRoleType": "Employee",
    "EmployeeID": "E8000",
    "isAssigned" : false,
    "ObjectID": "00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"
  },
  "emp4": {
    "BusinessPartnerFormattedName": " Lewandowski",
    "EmpRoleCode": "BUP803",
    "EmpRoleType": "Employee",
    "EmployeeID": "BUP803",
    "isAssigned" : false,
    "ObjectID": "00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"
  },
  "emp5": {
    "BusinessPartnerFormattedName": "Aleksandra",
    "EmpRoleCode": "BUP043",
    "EmpRoleType": "Employee",
    "EmployeeID": "BUP043",
    "isAssigned" : false,
    "ObjectID": "00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"
  },
  "emp6": {
    "BusinessPartnerFormattedName": "Eva Log",
    "EmpRoleCode": "BUP0d03",
    "EmpRoleType": "Employee",
    "EmployeeID": "BUP0d03",
    "isAssigned" : false,
    "ObjectID": "00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"
  }
}
```

I would like to put the employee where `EmployeeID` is equal to `E8000` **first** in list , **than** I want the employee where `isAssigned` is equal to `true` to follow

So far I've achieved this :

```
var sortedItems = _.sortBy(items, function(item) {
  return (item.isAssigned === true || item.EmployeeID === "E8000") ? 0 : 1;
});
```

But how to make sure that the emp with `EmployeeID` is equal `E8000` to will always be on top ?

Comment: yould you have more than three items? what should happen if more?

Comment: btw, you are trying to sort an object, because the array has only one item ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes I have like 99 items, but my code is a simple example

Comment: But as Nina said, you can't sort an object. Did you mean an array of objects? (without these `emp1`, `emp2` and so on) keys?

Comment: @kinduser Yes array of object, I've made some correction ( I'm sorry for confusion caused)

Comment: @NinaScholz It's an array of emp object, sorry for the confusion caused, I've edited and added corrections

Comment: do you have `'E8000'` with false?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, that specific emp is always true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You chain the wanted sort order.

```js
var array = [
        { name: "E8000 true", EmployeeID: "E8000", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8000 true", EmployeeID: "E8000", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8003 false", EmployeeID: "E8003", isAssigned : false },
        { name: "E8001 true", EmployeeID: "E8001", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8002 true", EmployeeID: "E8002", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8001 false", EmployeeID: "E8001", isAssigned : false }
    ];

array.sort((a, b) => 
    (b.EmployeeID === 'E8000') - (a.EmployeeID === 'E8000') ||
    b.isAssigned - a.isAssigned
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With lodash

```js
var array = [
        { name: "E8000 true", EmployeeID: "E8000", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8000 true", EmployeeID: "E8000", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8003 false", EmployeeID: "E8003", isAssigned : false },
        { name: "E8001 true", EmployeeID: "E8001", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8002 true", EmployeeID: "E8002", isAssigned : true },
        { name: "E8001 false", EmployeeID: "E8001", isAssigned : false }
    ];

console.log(_.sortBy(array, [
    o => o.EmployeeID !== 'E8000',
    o => !o.isAssigned
]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted danke schon :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you need lodash on this:

```
items.sort((a,b)=>{
    if(a.EmployeeID !== b.EmployeeID){
        if(a.EmployeeID === 'E8000') return -1;
        if(b.EmployeeID === 'E8000') return 1;
    };

    if(a.isAssigned !== b.isAssigned){
        return a.isAssigned ? -1 : 1;
    }

    //Remaining sort logic...
})
```

This translates to:

"When deciding if `a` or `b` should come first, if `a` and `b` don't both have the same EmployeeID value, check if either has value `E8000`.  If ether one does have that value, put that one first.

Otherwise, check if `a` and `b` have the same value for `isAssigned`, if they don't, put the one that has `true` as the `isAssigned` value first.

Finally if the prior conditions weren't met, follow whatever logic you want for setting which should go first.

Of course, you have to fill in whatever sort logic you want to come after that.  For example, if you want to sort alphabetically on `BusinessPartnerFormattedName`, you'd fill that `Remaining sort logic...` block with:

```
if(a.BusinessPartnerFormattedName < b.BusinessPartnerFormattedName) return -1;
if(a.BusinessPartnerFormattedName > b.BusinessPartnerFormattedName) return 1;
return 0;
```

Comment: I just love lodash, personal choice but thank for your vanilla approach

Comment: It doesn't make any sense... OP has an array of objects that have a nested object inside... Your solution will not solve it

Comment: @kinduser- You're correct!  Sorry, I thought the top level object was an array. napi15, this will NOT work if your top level object is not an array.

Comment: @DRich Seems like it fits OP issue:)

Answer (score 1):

The data you provided is highly misleading, however I still would like to publish my solution, because basically I just like it.

```js
const items = [{BusinessPartnerFormattedName:"Aleksandra Lewandowski",EmpRoleCode:"BUP003",EmpRoleType:"Employee",EmployeeID:"E7000",isAssigned:!0,ObjectID:"00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"},{BusinessPartnerFormattedName:"Aleksandra Lewandowski",EmpRoleCode:"BUP003",EmpRoleType:"Employee",EmployeeID:"E6000",isAssigned:!1,ObjectID:"00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"},{BusinessPartnerFormattedName:"Aleksandra Lewandowski",EmpRoleCode:"BUP003",EmpRoleType:"Employee",EmployeeID:"E8000",isAssigned:!1,ObjectID:"00163E0E46241ED7A0EA0590D0655967"}];
const helper = (emp) => emp.EmployeeID === 'E8000' ? 2 : +(!!emp.isAssigned);

const r = items.sort((a, b) => helper(b) - helper(a));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I would like to improve my question, would you mind telling me what is misleading so I can edit it ?

Comment: @napi15 So basically you have posted an array of objects, but inside these objects is a nested object with key "emp1", "emp2" and so on, and value of these keys is the employee object. So its like a nested structure, however all of published answers are related with flat array of objects (without these "emp1", "emp2" keys), just an array of employee objects

Comment: Oh ok , yes I noticed that all provided answer does not correspond to my nested structure , but I adapt the provided logic and thank you again for your answer